# Using react-router with typescript

Tags: typescript, reactjs, react-router

I'm attempting to port a small react app over to typescript.

I'm encountering issues with react-router.  I have the latest definitions from definitely type but the following code gives me errors:

```
var routes:Router.Route = (
<Route name="root" path="/" handler={MyApp}>
  <Route path="dashboard" handler={MyDash} />
  <DefaultRoute handler={SomeSection} />
  <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFoundPage} />
</Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function (Handler:React.Component<any, any>) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

These are the compilation errors I get:

```
js/app.tsx(31,3): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Component<RouteProp, any>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'render' is missing in type 'Component<RouteProp, any>'.
js/app.tsx(32,5): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Component<RouteProp, any>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
js/app.tsx(47,5): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Component<DefaultRouteProp, any>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'render' is missing in type 'Component<DefaultRouteProp, any>'.
js/app.tsx(49,5): error TS2605: JSX element type 'Component<NotFoundRouteProp, any>' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Property 'render' is missing in type 'Component<NotFoundRouteProp, any>'.
js/app.tsx(53,20): error TS2345: Argument of type '(Handler: Component<any, any>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(Handler: RouteClass, state: RouterState) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'Handler' and 'Handler' are incompatible.
    Type 'Component<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'RouteClass'.
js/app.tsx(54,17): error TS2604: JSX element type 'Handler' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

What is the correct way to initialize a set of react-router routes using typescript?

(I should clarify that I'm using a nightly typescript build which has support for JSX via the `--jsx react` flag

Comment: I had the same issue and it may be a problem with TypeScript's TSX support: [Typescript/3928](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3928).  I asked a similar question there, and they re-opened the issue.

Answer (score 15):

The root problem was some definitions in react-router not having an explicit render() method. This has been fixed (indirectly) by https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/5197

Note that this code is incorrect:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler:React.Component<any, any>) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

It should be:

```
Router.run(routes, function (Handler: new() => React.Component<any, any>) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

Because `Handler` is a *constructor* for a React component, not an instance of it.

Comment: Well, not free, since he had to spend time on the answer after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Errors in the type definitions appears to be the cause. You can work around them by modifying the `.d.ts` files as follows:

In `react.d.ts`, remove `render` from the `JSX.ElementClass` interface

```
interface ElementClass extends React.Component<any, any> {
}
```

In `react-router.d.ts`, change `run` method's `routes` parameter's type to `React.ReactElement<RouteProp>`

```
function run(routes: React.ReactElement<RouteProp>, callback: RouterRunCallback): Router;
function run(routes: React.ReactElement<RouteProp>, location: LocationBase, callback: RouterRunCallback): Router;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not in love with the idea of changing the .d.ts files.  There must be a way to make them work as is otherwise people wouldn't have published them to definitielyTyped.

Answer (score -1):

For making it running under typescript 1.6 with react-router, I've added the following code in the react-router.d.ts file :

```
interface RouterClass extends React.ComponentClass<any> {}

var Router: RouterClass;

//For Router

function createElement(

type: ReactRouter.RouterClass,

props: any,

...children: __React.ReactNode[]): ReactRouter.Router;

}

interface RouteProp {
    name?: string;
    path?: string;
    handler?: React.ComponentClass<any>;
    ignoreScrollBehavior?: boolean;
    component?: React.ComponentClass<any>;
}
```

Comment: Works fine after applying your changes.